Blended wing vs flying wing kitplanes, are there any out there that are in production, horsepower calculations,
There is this interesting plane I like, the horten hx2 and would like to make a 1:20 scale 3d model of this,
but wondered if you doubled an air frames size on such a plane over conventional wing design how much more horsepower would you need
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horten_Aircraft_HX-2
Crew: 2 Length: 4.5 m (14 ft 9 in) Wingspan: 10 m (32 ft 10 in) Gross weight: 600 kg (1,323 lb) Fuel capacity: 240 L (63 US gal; 53 imp gal) Powerplant: 1 × Rotax 912 iS2 4-cylinder air-cooled horizontally-opposed piston engine, 75 kW (100 hp)
https://robbreport.com/motors/aviation/the-horten-hx-2-flying-wing-launch-2898746/

Welcome Amari!  Here is a link to our community's tour: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/tour

And here is a link to our help site: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help

We do generally limit posts to a single question, so I'll flag your question as "needs more focus", which will give you an opportunity to edit it.  It may get closed, but that will just be temporary.  You can click on "Reopen" once you've made your edits.

I'll also give you an upvote because it's clear you aren't a spammer, your questions are good, and you may need some rep points to post comments.

A 1:20 scale model of a 10 m flying wing would be close to the venerable Zagi.  RC forums have decades of discussion about this and similar airplanes from other manufacturers.  But briefly, 200 W is more than enough for spirited flying.  Maybe 300 if you add heavy retractable landing gear and a heavy scale canopy to look like the HX-2.
